# Remove symbol from SQL statement result

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

Before I insert my data into SQLite3 DB I insert some data with symbols(e.g. `name (vlan name)`)

After I run my program with my return command function, it prints out:

```
x="create vlan"
y="global"
#
def readswitch():

        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x, y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

import database

print (database.readswitch())
```

result:

```
`[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]`
```

My expected result is

```
enable configure terminal vlan (number) name (vlan name)
```

More perfect result:

```
enable
configure terminal
vlan (number)
name (vlan name)
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `database.readswitch()` returns a list of tuples, and for each such tuple you only care about its first element, you can do

```
for result in database.readswitch():
    print result[0]
```

You can also do

```
a = '\n'.join([result[0] for result in database.readswitch()])
```

or

```
a = ' '.join([result[0] for result in database.readswitch()])
```

If you need to store this in a string